# Sign ILMerge'd DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild-task

I have a DLL that I have created using ILMerge (more specifically using the [MSBuild.ILMerge Task](https://ilmergemsbuild.codeplex.com/) tool) and I need the merged DLL to be strongly named.

The "original" DLL is signed using Visual Studio (done by creating a new key with password) however the merged DLL is not.

Ideally I'd like to sign the DLL as part of the build process, but I'm happy to do it afterwards (manually if need be).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the source Luke, the task has a KeyFile property.  Commented as "The target assembly will be signed with its contents and will then have a strong name".  So yes.

Comment: Sorry, I already tried this, there is an option in the task config file to specify a key file (which is defaulted to the _original key file_ or something like that, but it still doesn't sign it - if I put in an invalid value it gives me an error, but a valid value just does nothing.

Comment: Sigh.  Debug it.  If you don't know how then ask a question about it.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly constructive "find out for yourself" - I've found the answer thanks to somebody else who gave an actual answer rather than being flippant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install ILMerge stand-alone, you can pass the argument /keyfile, like:

```
ilmerge.exe /out:Merged.dll /keyfile:key.snk Primary.dll Secondary.dll
```

You can also sign it without merging, like:

```
ilmerge.exe /out:Merged.dll /keyfile:key.snk Primary.dll
```

Source: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ILMergeSigned.aspx

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your answer I'll give this a try, can I ask, is it possible to sign the DLL using ILMerge using the .pfx file, or do I need the .snk?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and see where I get

Comment: Thanks; this is what I did in the end - maybe when I have more time I can find the actual way of doing it in VS but this does the trick